# Trying to install tm package in R but it fails

Tags: r

Trying to install tm package in R but I get the following error.

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/resmim/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) also installing the dependency ‘slam’
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of   C/C++/Fortran: ‘slam’ ‘tm’   These will not be installed

Answer (score 3):

Type this in your console:

`chooseCRANmirror()`

And choose your CRAN Mirror. I like Spain :). Then try re-installing your package.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to trying your luck with a few different mirrors, be sure to answer 'N' when asked 'Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?' This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -2):

update r version to latest, it just worked for me.
to do this, download latest version of R from cran and install it. no uninstall required for previous versions.